# Error handling with loop and user input

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

```
For i = 1 To repNumber
    TryAgain:
    On Error GoTo ErrH:

    repName = InputBox("Enter rep name you want to exclude.", "Name of Rep")
    .PivotItems(repName).Visible = False
Next i

ErrH:
        MsgBox "Try Again"
        GoTo TryAgain:
```

It shows an error if I type in Rep name that doesn't exist in the PivotTable. So I'm trying to use an error handler to let a user type Rep name again.
But after the second time I type something wrong, instead of going to the  error handler, the code terminates itself.

I'm not sure if 'On Error GoTo' is in the wrong line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Resume TryAgain` instead of `GoTo TryAgain`.

(You don't need `:` in these statements, it is by coincidence allowed because it is also used to seperate multiple statements within a line, so it is just meaningless here).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `Error Handing` and `GoTo` statements all together (which is definitely best practice) by testing within the code itself and using `If` blocks and `Do` loops (et. al.).

See this code which should accomplish the same thing:

```
Dim pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Set pf = PivotTables(1).PivotField("myField") 'adjust to your needs

For i = 1 To repNumber

    Do

        Dim bFound As Boolean
        bFound = False

        repName = InputBox("Enter rep name you want to exclude.", "Name of Rep")

        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

            If pi.Value = repName Then
                pi.Visible = False
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next pi

    Loop Until bFound = True

Next i
```